# Two facebook buttons with different callbacks on the same page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

In my website's login page, there's a form with two tabs : one to login, one to register.

There's a button to register with facebook, and the callback points to `/complete-profile` to allow the user to enter his details before registering.

The's also a button to login with facebook, and the callback points to `/login` where I fetch the user with the matching Facebook ID, if it exists.

Since both forms are in the same page, I have to use `getLoginUrl()` twice, since the two buttons have different callbacks.

```
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/website/login', $permissions);
$registerUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/website/complete-profile', $permissions);
```

Using the register buttons work, since its URL was created last, but the login button does not work. This is the message I get : **Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.**

I did a bit of reading, and it seems I'm getting the error because the CSRF token for the first loginUrl gets overwritten by the second one, when I make the call to get the registerUrl.

Is there any way to generate two Facebook login buttons with different callbacks on the same page? Or do I have to resort to using two different pages for the login and the registration, which really isn't convenient.

Comment: I think most implementations return the user to the same url and redirect/render differently based on his status. Alternatively, I'm pretty sure you'd have to create two different $helper or possibly $fb objects.